# React-native decoded base64 encoded string

Tags: react-native, base64, jwt

I try to decode base64 encoded string token in react native, atob not work and library like js-base64 not resolve the problem.

Someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

atob and btoa are not supported in JavascriptCore but works when the app runs under Chrome debugger, because JS code runs in Chrome when debugged. There are many base64 modules. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/base64 works fine for me.

Answer (score 26):

I find some simple way worked for me, the same api as node.

Install buffer

```
yarn add buffer
```

Usage:

```
console.log(Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64'));
console.log(Buffer.from("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'));
```

Comment: and to use it in react native, need to add the import
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

Comment: spent many hours trying to get ImagePicker to send to AWS S3 as a jpg blob. Buffer has worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to install this **react-native-base64** package and use it as below in react native.

npm install --save react-native-base64

```
import base64 from 'react-native-base64'
base64.encode('Some string to encode to base64'); 
base64.decode('VGhlIG51bWJlciBpcyA2MDAwMCwgd2hpY2ggY2FuIGJlIHJlYWQgYXMgc2l4dHkgdGhvdXNhbmQuJm5ic3A7PEJSPg==')
```