# how to decode base 64 jpg image in Reactjs or React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the follow rest api data which I am trying to decode as base 64 jpg image. Looks like the string has some extra leading and trailing charters. I am not sure where to start. I have an react native (node) project where I need to encode this. I am not sure where to start. Looking for an example of how to encode or decode this

```
{"icon":"data:image\/jpg;base64,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\">"}
```

Comment: Do you really need to decode it, or display it?

Comment: Just need to display it

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786668/react-native-decoded-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: You can use the `<Image />` component from RN, and use it as `source={{ uri: icon }}` (or similar, YMMV).

Comment: As a side note, ReactJS and React Native are two different technologies. An answer for one might be different than an answer for another.